# Can we use column formatter with command set customizer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset, fieldcustomizers

Can we use the listview command set extension to change the format of the view or column in SharePoint online? If yes, how?

And is there any other way to create a template like feature for this? Probably a REST API to call in which we send the JSON object and list name ant it gets applied to the list?

Actually I want to create a type of template or something, clicking on which, the predefined JSON object would be used to change the view or column.

Comment: Do you want to create Field customizer with list view command set??

Comment: @GaneshSanap No, I want to create a command button (which can be done using the microsoft command set customizer docs), on clicking which should implement my already created JSON object for column/ view formatter to the specified list.

Comment: I am new to SharePoint so I am not sure if this is even possible. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Is it possible to do what you said in the comment? If it can be done, can you point out any example or resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this few days back, I created a command set customizer extension to create two buttons.One to customize the fields and another to customize the view. I stored some JSONs in different files. and displayed dropdown to select between  the JSONs. Then After that I was needed to replace the fields name to the available fields. To do that, I kept variable names in JSON and during the sending of the JSON to API, I replaced the filed names with the original selected field name.

I sent the JSON in the attribute "CustomFormatter" and used the merge REST API. And it worked.

[image: On right side the panel opens up on clicking the customize field button]

[image: On clicking any field, the JSON selection dropdown is shown.]